# get date in a URL in HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to get the right Time form in URL in HTML code but I'm not sure how to set that .

I tried something like this:
`<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/easycall/dp/#" + DD + "." + MM "." + YYYY>Home</a>`

what I need at the end is somthing like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/easycall/dp/17.02.2017

Comment: if you are using php (I am not php guy)
You could try something like
<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/easycall/dp/<?php echo date("d.m.Y"); ?>">Home</a>

Comment: You'll have to use JavaScript to do that, as far as I can tell.

Comment: could you inform me more about how to do that in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ton Gok, welcome to StackOverflow.

HTML doesn't support this functionality by itself--it's a static markup language, and you're looking for something dynamic to happen within that.

Some options (among many):

1. Use JavaScript's document.createElement() (etc.) to create the anchor element (the `<a href...>`) dynamically.
2. Give your anchor element an `id` attribute, then use JavaScript's document.getElementById() (etc.) to change its `href` attribute to what you want.
3. More along the lines of what you were trying to do: Use a server-side language, like PHP, or a [template engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system#Server-side_systems), to inject the value into the HTML before it's delivered to the client.  This option has one disadvantage compared to JavaScript, that you have to get into working with software on your web server.  But on most projects this is likely something you will need for other reasons anyway.

Whichever option you do, you'll have to open a bit of a learning can-of-worms and get into some programming; if after some homework there you can't find a solution, post a new question here with details on which language you are trying to use and what you've tried.

Comment: Thank you so much for your Help and I appreciate your advice.